# AS3 - Sound Channel no repeat but plays other channel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here's my question

On my Main Stage I added this code to have a sound repeat, it works fine on this stage and loops well

```
var HP1sound:Sound = new HP_sound();

var HP_channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

function playSound():void
{
    HP_channel=HP1sound.play();
    HP_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function onComplete(event:Event):void

{
    SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete);
    playSound();
}
    playSound();
```

However, I have added the code to another page (and changed all the variables) and the correct sound plays one time correctly, however, when it should loop it plays the first stage's sound. (2nd page code shown below)

```
var Crow_sound2:Sound = new Crow_sound();

var Crow_channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

function playSound2():void

{
    Crow_channel=Crow_sound2.play();

    Crow_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function onComplete2(event:Event):void
{
    SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete);

     playSound2();
}
 playSound2();
```

So it's playing sound playSound2 on the repeat it plays playSound

any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change `onComplete` to `onComplete2` on these lines:

```
Crow_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete);
```

They should be:

```
Crow_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete2);
SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete2);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for taking the time to answer i'll give it a go now! didn't realise onComplete was a variable/nameable value.